# Prove that $x_n$ converge if subsequences $(x_{2n})$, $(x_{2n+1})$ and $(x_{3n})$ converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that the subsequences subsequences $(x_{2n})$, $(x_{2n+1})$ and $(x_{3n})$ converge. Prove that $x_n$ converge. I want to prove that all the subsequences that converge, converge to the same point. In other words, I want to prove that their limit is the same. (If not, $x_n$ doesn't converge) Though, I don't know how to go about to proving $\lim(x_{2n})=\lim(x_{2n+1})$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2274266/42969.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x_{3n})$ has a subsequence which is a subsequence of $(x_{2n})$. $(x_{3n})$ also has another subsequence which is a subsequence of $(x_{2n+1})$, you are ready to claim that they all converge to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Can you think of any subsequence $x_{\text{something depending on $n$}}$ that would be a subsequence of both $x_{2n}$ and $x_{3n}?$